# 日本語に違和感: 「自分の質問に対して回答する」の補足「知識を共有する、 Q&A 形式」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

対象: 質問を投稿する画面

[image: self-answer]

Comment: 翻訳を適用しました。次回のビルドに適用するはずです。リンク先のオプションを検討しています。

Comment: リンク先が英語な件について、別の質問に分けました: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%A3%9C%E8%B6%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E5%85%88

Answer (score 1):

> Q&A 形式で情報共有しましょう