# 英語が残っている: 「自分の質問に対して回答する」への補足のリンク先

Tags: バグ, 調査中, 翻訳, 英語

### 対象:

質問を投稿するフォームの一番下のチェック欄の、

> 自分の質問に対して回答する – [Q&A 形式で情報共有しましょう](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.217476625.608059777.1699896430-241265131.1694604651)

という文字列のリンク先です（これが出現するのは、信用度が15以上のユーザー）。

スクリーンショット:

> [image: self-answer]

### 英語が残っている箇所:

リンク先が英語のブログ記事です:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

<sub>この質問は、 [日本語に違和感: 「自分の質問に対して回答する」の補足「知識を共有する、 Q&A 形式」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/30/32986) から分離したものです。</sub>

Comment: 自由にリンク先を変えることができます。メタで説明するポストを書けばそこへリンクもできるし、リンクを外すことだけも可能。どうしましょうか？

Comment: @jmac この箇所だけでなく全体を見て決めたいですね。ということで[全体を見るためのポスト](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E5%86%85%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E3%82%84-%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7/91#91)を投稿しました。

Comment: 現在は「Q&A形式にして、あなたの知識を共有しましょう!」という文字列になっていて、リンクになっていませんでした。より正確には、翻訳時に[リンクが消されていました](https://ja.traducir.win/string/2108)。

Comment: 2020 年 3 月現在は、リンクが有効になっています。また、 [ja.traducir.win の当該文字列](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12515) を見る限りでは、翻訳の段階でリンクを消す、といったことは出来ないと考えられます。

Comment: 2014年から動きが無く、今となってはどのように対応する予定だったのか不明なため、「調査中」へ差し戻させて頂きました。Stack Exchange社での再検討をお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

下記のどちらかの対応を希望します。

- リンク先URLを、既に翻訳済みのヘルプ記事 `/help/self-answer`（[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)）に変更する
- リンク先URLを、翻訳文字列に含めて通常の翻訳フローで変更可能にする